# How to create a button with many states?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am a beginner in React Native and am in a situation where I need a single button to had four states.

The four states are Accept, Recall, Start, and Close.

It will work as follows:

Pressing 'Accept' -> Will become 'Recall'

Pressing 'Recall' -> Will become 'Start'

Pressing 'Start' -> Will become 'Close'

Each time I press the button, I send the states to my database, so that all the actions are saved, each in its respective hour, minute and second.

I have no idea how to do this, so I do not have any code to post here, I did some research, but I can not find the right key words to find what I need.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The reason you can't find it is because it's a really bad design idea that nobody should ever do...

Comment: @niet why? I don't think it has to be necessarily bad design, for sure it can be implemented badly.

Comment: Well... what happens if someone double-clicks the button? Does it cycle through two states without the user knowing what happened?

Comment: But if he would send a state identifier itself, the server could reject the second click ...

Comment: When the user clicks on the button I will put a logic where a modal appears to confirm this action, if it clicks 'Yes' I send the information to the database, and only after that the modal disappears. When back the button will to the second state, and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a live example on React (in react-native it should be nearly same)
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNJOvL?editors=0010

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  state = {
    type: 'Accept'
  }

  types = ["Accept", "Recall", "Start", "Close"];

  doCall = (type) => {
    // requests here
    const nextType = this.types[this.types.indexOf(this.state.type) + 1];
    if (nextType) {
      this.setState({type: nextType});
    } else {
      // action you want to do if "Close" is pressed
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {type} = this.state;
    return (<button
              onClick={() => this.doCall(type)}
            >
              {type}
            </button>);
  }
}

React.render(<Button />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Supposing the button is the submit button of a form
then this form has to contain an hidden <input tag with name='next_button_value'>...

Are you using php? if so the $_REQUEST["next_button_value"] variable will be containing what you want to output at the button value... you can also customize your button's and form actions accordingly to this value with if ($_REQUEST["nbv"] == "blah") {Do as you have to do if it's blah...
}

Comment: I'm developing a app in react-native, I'll try to implementing this, thank you